# Moving background of the Gallery on the SmartWatch in "parallax scrolling"

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I would like to implement the same effect as the homescreen of the watch does:

In the background of a transparent Gallery with some icons on each item there should be an image, that will be moving in parallax, when ListItem is changing.

The only possibility that I can think about - is to use a FrameLayout to place an ImageView in the back and a Gallery in the front. And then, through Animation, as used in SampleControlExtension, substitute the image of the background every X millisecond.

There is no touch-move event, coming from the watch, only a swipe, but even it is not sent to the host, when the underlying view is a gallery. The only method, that is called upon sliding - is "ControlExtension.onListItemSelected", which is called from private final method "handleControlIntent".

But when I get "onListItemSelected" - it is too late .. list item has already changed - so my animation (which by the way of course is not so smooth as the real one) is performed afterwards.

Am I missing something?
Maybe there is a simpler solution for my problem?

Comment: I have also tried putting another ImageView as an overlay in front of the Gallery, hoping to block the ListItemSelected in this way, to catch the swipe and set the list item manually, but it didn't help: No swipe is returned, still the LIstItemSelected.